# Gurobi: Modified Q diagonals

Tags: debugging, runtime, gurobi

I'm using Python and Gurobi to formulate and solve optimization problems.
When solving my current formulation, I get the output `Modified 2 Q diagonals` many times. Oftentimes, instead of `2`, other numbers like `12` or `14` appear.

I googled, but I could not find any documentation on what that means. I still get a valid solution, but it seems to take longer. Do I have to rewrite my constraints in a certain way?

Comment: This is to fix Q so it remains numerically positive semi definite. Most likely your quadratic matrices are border line PSD or not PSD. Usually this is not something to worry about. Gurobi will complain if the problem is really non-convex.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen This is correct, and should be given as the answer to the question.